# Why is this error thrown in my code - Python?

Tags: python

Why does this error appear?

Error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27_1\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1410, in __call_
    return self.func(*args)
  File "editor.py", line 90, in onOpen
    fileopened = open(fno, "w+")
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, file found
```

Code on:

https://code.google.com/p/childreneditor/source/browse/trunk/editor-new.py

Comment: Paste in the line where "fno" is defined.

Comment: Please post the code in the question.  Do not use a third party site to host important parts of your question (code).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well when you open a file, you need the path... the fno is a class, but if you do: 
fileopened = open(fno.name, "w+") it should do the trick...

fno.name gives you the path with which you opened the file with the askopenfile.

Answer (score 4):

`askopenfile` returns the opened file to you, not its name, so there's no need to call `open` on it. If you really want the name, you can use `askopenfilename` instead, but it doesn't seem necessary for what you're doing.

Answer (score 1):

It's just like it says:

```
fileopened = open(fno, "w+")
```

That's the line of code that had a problem.

```
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, file found
```

That's what the problem was.

`w+` is a string, so clearly it's `fno` that causes the problem. The problem is that a `string or buffer` is needed, and it's actually a `file`. You need a `string or buffer` because that's the file-name parameter for `open`. The purpose of `open` is to open files given a file name; but you already have a file.

So just use the file.

Answer (score 0):

"fno" in your code is a file object and open() expects receive string or unicode
see http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#open